# Postgres - pg-promise - Unable to update multi rows - Missing FROM-clause entry for table "y"

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I have a project where I need to update a features of items that are linked to a plot. The API call gets a list of features. I first do a search in the database to find all exciting feature_id's for that specific plot.

Then I update all the plots that have that are contained within the array of exciting id's and I insert all those who are not.

The inserting part works fine. But I have a problem with the updating. If I want to update I always get the following error `error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "y"`

```js
    const values = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i += 1) {
      const feature = features[i];

      values.push({
        feature_id: feature.id,
        plot_id: plotId,
        type: feature.type,
        area: feature.area,
        created_on: currendDate,
        updated_on: currendDate,
        geo_feature: feature.geoFeature,
      });
    }

    const insert = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['plot_id', 'type', 'area', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'geo_feature'], { table: 'features' });
    const update = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?feature_id', 'plot_id', 'type', 'area', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'geo_feature'], { table: 'features' });

    const insertingFeatures = values.find(
      (value) => !excistingFeaturesIds.includes(value.feature_id),
    );
    const updatingFeatures = values.find(
      (value) => excistingFeaturesIds.includes(value.feature_id),
    );

    if (insertingFeatures) {
      const insertQuery = pgp.helpers.insert(
        insertingFeatures, insert,
      );

      await promiseDB.none(insertQuery);
    }

    if (updatingFeatures) {
      const updateQuery = `${pgp.helpers.update(
        updatingFeatures, update,
      )} WHERE v.feature_id = t.feature_id`;

      await promiseDB.none(updateQuery);
    }
```

This is the value of the `updateQuery` It seams that there is no from clause. I do not know why this happens (I have removed the coordinates from the query):

```sql
update "features" set "plot_id"='3',"type"='roof',"area"=342.01520314642977,"created_on"='2021-07-14T13:21:25.746+02:00',"updated_on"='2021-07-14T13:21:25.746+02:00',"geo_feature"='{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[...]},"properties":{"UIDN":6338864,"OIDN":5290477,"VERSIE":1,"BEGINDATUM":"2015-09-23","VERSDATUM":"2015-09-23","TYPE":1,"LBLTYPE":"hoofdgebouw","OPNDATUM":"2015-08-25","BGNINV":5,"LBLBGNINV":"kadastralisatie","type":"roof","tools":"polygon","description":"D1","id":5290477,"area":342.01520314642977,"roofType":"saddle","roofGreen":"normal","database":true},"id":1}' WHERE v.feature_id = t.feature_id
```

Comment: You should debug your code better. Start by logging the queries - event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) can help with that.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for the tip. I have done that and I have outputted the result in the question. It seems that my query does not contain a from clause. I do not know why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you do not account for the SQL syntax difference between single-row and multi-row updates. [It is in the documentation](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update).

Your `updatingFeatures` ends up being a single object, and so a single-row update is generated, one that does not have any `FROM` clause, because it is not supposed to, and you are then appending invalid `WHERE` clause to it.

If you want a generic multi-row update to be generated, make sure `updatingFeatures` is always an array of objects, and not just one object.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have swapped the `find` to a `filter`this always returns an array.